# Определение координат крайней точки вращающегося отрезка

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Я хочу определить координаты крайней точки вращающегося отрезка в Corona SDK.
Для визуальной проверки полученных координат, добавил пару строк кода для зарисовки окружностей. Получилось вот что:

[image]

Как мы видим, полученные координаты ошибочные. Не подскажите, где ошибка?

```
PI = math.pi
length = 100

x1 = display.contentCenterX
y1 = display.contentCenterY
x2 = x1 + length
y2 = y1 + length

alfa = 0
dalfa = 4

line = display.newLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
line.anchorSegments = true
line.anchorX = 0.1
line.anchorY = 0.1
line.strokeWidth = 3

function moveR()
    angle = (2 * PI) - ((alfa * PI) / 180)   -- переводим градусы в радианы с учетом периода в 2 пи
    x2 = length * math.sin(corner) + x1       -- считаем новые координаты точки по оси х
    y2 = length * math.cos(corner) + y1       -- считаем новые координаты по оси у
    local myCircle = display.newCircle( x2, y2, 1 )
end

function flop()
    line.anchorX = 0
    line.anchorY = 0
    line.x = x2
    line.y = y2

end

function update()
    moveR()
    if alfa >= 360 then
        alfa = 0
    end
    line.rotation = alfa
    --print(line.rotation)
    alfa = alfa + dalfa
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "tap", flop )
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", update )
```

Comment: не `corner`, a `angle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме этого момента:

```
x2 = x1 + length
y2 = y1 + length
```

остальное выглядит нормально (но я не знаю сути anchorX). Здесь правда подразумевалась линия длиной 141 под углом 45?

Comment: cпасибо за подсказку. Правильно вот так:                                                                                        
`x2 = x1 + length
y2 = display.contentCenterY`

Comment: Это решило проблему или дело ещё в чём-то?

Comment: Это проблема полностью решена. Спасибо. Но возникла другая. Вопрос уже по использованию SDK. К вам можно обратиться? Или лучше создать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: Лучше отдельный